# How to fix the height of row in angulat-mat-table

Tags: mat-table

I have a table with a column which is very large, by default the angular material table is adjusting the row-height to fit the contents .
Is there a work around where I can fix the row-height so that a scroll appears on that particular row when the given height exceeds(not the table)?

Answer (score 0):

To adjust rows height use the following style:

```
tr.mat-row { height: 20px; }
```